# should I use margin 0 auto or position, top, left to align content to center

Tags: css

I'd like to know what is the best way to center content in the middle and center. I mean, is it best to use "margin" property or I should use position: absolute and top, left properties? What are pros and cons of using one of them for this purpose?

Comment: can you try [this](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use this *(when you know the size of the thing you are centering)*-**

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

**or this *(when you don't know the size of the thing you are centering)*-**

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Source:** https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/